# Recursive union/ Union in a Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a complex view which returns me a set of records. All I need to do is "artificially" inflate this number (to investigate an issue which only occurs with high data volume), for which I thought I can simply UNION ALL The query with itself. This works in theory:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, .... FROM <Table> WHERE <Some Condition>

UNION ALL

SELECT column1, column2, column3, .... FROM <Table> WHERE <Some Condition>

UNION ALL

SELECT column1, column2, column3, .... FROM <Table> WHERE <Some Condition>

UNION ALL ... ...
```

I don't want to repeat this union 1000 times, is there some better way for me to recursively do this, or all the union statements in a while loop? Unfortunately I can't create stored procedures, it has be done by running the query in SSMS directly.

I did try something like this:

```
Declare @ctr as integer;
Set @Ctr = 0;
While @Ctr < 10
BEGIN

With cte as (Select ......)
select * from cte
UNION ALL
select * from cte
set @Ctr = @ctr + 1
```

This did to the union, but it did it returned me 10 different results each with the union done 10 times.

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If this task is just a one time thing for you to do some investigating, you're probably better off just copy and pasting your "Select... Union All" query about one thousand times and executing that.  (you can paste that code into notepad or something like 10 times, copy that, and then past that whole thing another 10 times.. etc..)

Comment: It is a one-time thing, but I'd like to learn how to do something like this other than copy pasting. I know it will take me longer to figure this out than to copy paste but in the long run that knowledge might help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you just want simply repeat your data 1000 times, you could do it this way

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM 
 (SELECT column1, column2, column3, .... FROM <Table> WHERE <Some Condition>) t
cross apply (select top 1000 * from master..spt_values) a   -- you could use any table with 1000+ records, or any number tables
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would try to go about it.

```
DECLARE @Tables TABLE(TableName NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @Tables SELECT 'MyHardCodedTable1'
INSERT INTO @Tables SELECT 'MyHardCodedTable2'
INSERT INTO @Tables SELECT SO.Name FROM SYSOBJECTS SO WHERE SO.XType = 'U'

DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE  X CURSOR FOR SELECT TableName FROM @Tables
OPEN X
FETCH NEXT FROM X INTO @TableName
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0) BEGIN
    PRINT 'SELECT column1, column2, column3, .... FROM '+@TableName+' WHERE <Some Condition>' +CHAR(10)+CHAR(13) + 'UNION ALL '+CHAR(10)
    FETCH NEXT FROM X INTO @TableName
END
CLOSE X
DEALLOCATE X
```

Comment: Thanks Ross, I'll try this out as well